# jQuery override css hide on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden div that I show when the mouse hovers.

Then when I click the text changes and I want the div to be permanently shown. The problem is that it disappears again when the mouse moves off.

Is there a way in jQuery to override the mouse out hide in the css?

Thanks

CSS

```
.saveCompare {
    display:none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color:#BDD455;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
}

.listingContainer:hover .saveCompare {
  display: inline;
}
```

jQuery

```
        $("div.saveCompare").click(function() {
            $(this).text('Compare Added');
            $(this).show();
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: in your `mouseout` event callback, check if the text has changed. if it has don't hide it. if it hasnt, go ahead and hide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats probably because of your "display:none" in the ".saveCompare". The div still has this class. So its going to hide the div.
Maybe you can write a new class:

```
.saveCompareNew {
    display:inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color:#BDD455;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

And then use this call to remove your old class and add your new class

```
.removeClass("saveCompare").addClass("saveCompareNew")
```

Thats probably no the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: nice quick solution does work well. Although I will redo in the long term to avoid two similar classes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before you hide the form on `mouseout` do a check

```
$('#yourElement').hover(function(){
   //show your form
},function(){
   if (!textHasChanged)
      //hide your form
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to manipulate pseudo-classes in JavaScript (correct me if I'm wrong). You could go for a all-jQuery solution with sth like this:

```
$('.saveCompare').hide(); //you could do this in the CSS as well    
$('.listingContainer').hover(function(){
   $(this).children('.saveCompare').show(); //on mouse over show child .saveCompare
},function(){
   $(this).children('.saveCompare').hide(); //on mouse out hide child .saveCompare
});
$('.saveCompare').click(function(){
  $(this).append('<p>Added</p>').parent('.listingContainer').unbind(); //remove parent element's hover handler when clicked and show .saveCompare forever
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Nice solution. I am going to look further into unbind, good tool to have

Comment: Pay attention when using `unbind` with `hover` as `$(this).unbind('hover')` will not work, but you will have to use `$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')` instead. A plain `$(this).unbind()` like in my example will unbind all events.